# xDocument Remove Element base on sub-element value

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to remove an element from an xml file based on it's sub-element value.

my xml is formated like this:
[image: my xml format]

I want to remove the CB element if it's sub-element CBA has the value of AXIS.

This is what I'm trying, the compiler isn't giving me any errors, but it's also not doing removing the element.

```
string portXML = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\port.xml";
XDocument _port = XDocument.Load(portXML);
_port.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name("CBA").Value == "AXIS").Remove();
_port.Save(portXML);
```

I'm not familiar with how attributes/elements and xDoc, so I apologies if this is a stupid question.

Comment: you'll have to call to get the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
string portXML = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\port.xml";
            XDocument _port = XDocument.Load(portXML);
             _port.Descendants("CB").Where(e => e.Element("CBA").Value == "AXIS").Remove();
            _port.Save(portXML);
```